# How to set Spring boot HashMap in AWS Paramstore value and read via @ConfigurationProperties?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-parameter-store

In my `spring boot` application I have some externalized configuration properties read from `AWS Parameter Store`. I do not use `AWS SSM Client` directly and extract the properties. I am using the `spring-cloud-starter-aws-parameter-store-config` and with few `bootstrap.yml` changes I am able to configure it. When the application starts, I am able to automatically detect the environment property source and extract configuration values with the help of `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation.

Sample bootstrap.yml is shown below:

```
aws:
  paramstore:
    enabled: true
    name: my-app
    prefix: /config
    profileSeparator: /
```

Sample code is shown below:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("app.property")
public class TestObject {
  private Map<String, InnerObject> valueMap = new HashMap<>();

  @Getter
  @Setter
  @AllArgsConstructor
  @NoArgsConstructor
  public static class InnerObject {
    private int property_one = 20;
    private int property_two = 10;
  }
}
```

Sample AWS Parameter Store configuration name:

```
/config/my-app/dev/app.property.valueMap
```

All other properties (`String` & `StringList`) works fine except with map. I was unable to figure out the way to define this map as a value within the `AWS Parameter Store` such that it resolves into my `Java` `HashMap`. Your insights are highly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to figure out a way to define a whole `Java HashMap` as a value of the `AWS Paramstore` value. However, I was able to define each property of the map separately as shown below.

First entry of the map:

```
/config/my-app/dev/app.property.valueMap.key_one.property_one
/config/my-app/dev/app.property.valueMap.key_one.property_two
```

Second entry of the map:

```
/config/my-app/dev/app.property.valueMap.key_two.property_one
/config/my-app/dev/app.property.valueMap.key_two.property_two
```

This maybe not the most optimum or the best solution. However, it did the job done even though I had to define each value individually. Hope this would help someone, Thanks!